Is it necessary to switch from the Hosted XML to the Inheritance Process Model after a migration
Let's say I have a Team Project Collection that was originally created on an old Team Foundation Server version. Thus, all Team Projects in that collection were created based on different XML file-based Process Templates.
Now, let's say that Team Project Collection gets first migrated to the latest available Azure DevOps Server version and from there to Azure DevOps Services, as described here. In that case, all Team Projects in that collection on Azure DevOps Services use the Hosted XML process model.
As far as I know, it should be possible to move these Team Projects to the Inheritance process model in which case I no longer need to manually modify XML files and can do customizations via web user interface.
But would I have to do this or is this purely an optional step?
I'm asking because upgrading Team Foundation Server / Azure DevOps Server in the past sometimes made it necessary to modify the Process Templates used by Team Projects to enable new features, etc.
Is that also necessary from time to time if I stay on the Hosted XML process model on Azure DevOps Services, e.g. when new features are rolled out by Microsoft?


As far as I know, it should be possible to move these Team Projects to the Inheritance process model.

Yes, it's supported to move from Hosted XML to an inherited process when using Azure DevOps service.

But would I have to do this or is this purely an optional step?

It's an optional step. Upgrading a Hosted XML process model to an inherited process provides the convenience of customizing your work tracking system through the user interface. The Inheritance process model supports most customizations, and also supports moving projects to a different process, cloning process and REST API, which are not supported in a Hosted XML process. However, some features like disabling system rules and steps (for other than Test Case) are not supported in the Inherited model but are supported in the Hosted XML model. See the detailed info from Differences between Inheritance and Hosted XML.

Is that also necessary from time to time if I stay on the Hosted XML process model on Azure DevOps Services, e.g. when new features are rolled out by Microsoft?

If you use Hosted XML process in Azure DevOps Service, you still need to modify your XML to enable the new features. The Hosted XML process model provides support for customizing work tracking objects and Agile tools for a project by modifying and importing a process template.

Is it necessary to switch from the Hosted XML to the Inheritance Process Model after a migration

Whether it's necessary to switch to the inheritance process model depends on your specific needs and how comfortable you are with managing customizations through XML files. If you prefer a more user-friendly interface for managing customizations and don’t mind the limitations of the inheritance process model, it would be a good choice to use inheritance process. Otherwise, staying on the Hosted XML process model.
